# Firebase in app messaging on action button click how to open new activity

Tags: firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

I am trying Model layout of Firebase in-app messaging. On model I have added one button. and for that button action, I have provided the firebase dynamic link. So when the user is clicking on button dynamic link is getting a trigger. and it's first opening the browser and after that, it's again coming to application. This interaction is not looking more natural. I want to open the new page on click of the action button. But on click of action button first browser is getting open. How to solve this issue?

Comment: is any solution work for you?

Answer (score 4):

You can implement FirebaseInAppMessagingClickListener in your mainActivity and initialize in onCreate() method using FirebaseInAppMessaging.getInstance().addClickListener(MainActivity.this);
for more details please click below link-

https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/modify-message-behavior?platform=android

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to achieve this would be to extend your `MainActivity` with `FirebaseInAppMessagingClickListener` if you know that the In-App Message will be triggered there & then create & Intent & open another activity.

Add the messageClicked function to your class:

```
    @Override
    public void messageClicked(InAppMessage inAppMessage, Action action) {
        // Determine which URL the user clicked
        String url = action.getActionUrl();

        // Get general information about the campaign
        CampaignMetadata metadata = inAppMessage.getCampaignMetadata();

        // Trigger an Intent to another class
    }
```

And register it (in your MainActivity) too:

```
FirebaseInAppMessaging.getInstance().addClickListener(this);
```

*PS: In the case that you schedule your In-App Message to be triggered on a certain event, implement this code in the activity there.*